# if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') and android post request not working

Tags: php, android

I am very new to android development and I am trying to connect a login with web server.But my Post request method in php gives error.I don't know about the things quite clear.I am using volley string request in my code to get connected.

**Here's my dbconnect.php code :**

```
 define('HOST','127.0.0.1');

 define('USER','root');

 define('PASS','');

 define('DB','registration');   // database

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

**Here's My Php Code :**

```
    if (  $_SERVER  [  '    REQUEST_METHOD  ']   ==   'POST') 

  {

  $username  =  $_POST['username'];

 $email = $_POST['email'];

 $password = $_POST['password'];

 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "INSERT INTO signin (username,password,email) VALUES('nabeel','nabeel12@ucp.edu','manofsteel2')";


    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo "Successfully Registered";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Could not register";
    }
  }

 else
 {

   echo ' this error';

 }
```

**My Android Code :**

```
private void registerUser() {

    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            return params;
        }

    };


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


   stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
           10000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
   ));


}
```

When I run only php code it doesn't run the  `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')`  it moves to else condition echo " This error "

It will be great to help in this code.This is my first try in connectivity so I didn't know the things quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use POST by running the PHP file. However GET can be tested by appending the params in the URL.
To test your PHP file/API you have 2 workarounds.

1. Change POST to GET in android and PHP as-well and test it. Once the test is done you can change it to POST. If it works with GET it will work with POST aswell.
   You can check the PHP directly by accessing `http://yourdomain.com/example.php?username=something&password=something&email=something`
2. If you are not happy with the first technique, you can [this](http://You%20can%20directly%20use%20POST%20by%20running%20the%20PHP%20file.%20However%20GET%20can%20be%20tested%20by%20appending%20the%20params%20in%20the%20URL.%20To%20test%20your%20PHP%20file/API%20you%20have%202%20workarounds.%20%201.%20Change%20POST%20to%20GET%20in%20android%20aswell%20and%20test%20it.%20Once%20the%20test%20is%20done%20you%20can%20change%20it%20to%20POST.%20If%20it%20works%20with%20GET%20it%20will%20work%20with%20POST%20aswell.%20You%20can%20check%20the%20PHP%20directly%20by%20accessing%20%60http://yourdomain.com/example.php?username=something&password=something&email=something%60%20%202.%20If%20you%20are%20not%20happy%20with%20the%20first%20technique,%20you%20can%20this%20a%20Chrome%20plugin.%20It's%20Postman.%20It's%20mean't%20for%20REST%20client%20testing.%20You%20select%20the%20method%20to%20%60POST%60%20and%20pass%20the%20parameters.%20That's%20it.%20https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) a Chrome plugin. It's Postman. It's mean't for REST client testing. You select the method to `POST` and pass the parameters. That's it.